# Copy Single file to multiple directories [overwrite if there]

Tags: powershell, active-directory

Im trying to write a script that will copy a file from one network location then copy it to a list of user's roaming profiles [also on a net share].  User's are entered into a csv as input.

Roaming profiles are on \fs-11\profiles[name]\AppData\Roaming\

```
cls
$input = Import-csv "\\fs-12\temp\input.csv"
$source = "\\fs-12\temp\filename.txt"

Function copyFile {
    Param( [string] $_username )
    Copy-Item -path $source -Destination "\\fs-11\profiles\"$_username"\AppData\Roaming\" -Force
    write-host ("filename.txt written to "$_username"'s profile")
}

foreach ($user in $input) {
    copyFile $user.username
}
```

This is throwing the following...

ERROR: Unexpected token '_username' in expression or statement.
copy2.ps1 (10): ERROR: At Line: 10 char: 51
ERROR: +     write-host ("System.mdw written to "$_username <<<< "'s profile")
ERROR:     + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (_username:String) [], ParseException
ERROR:     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken
ERROR:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are terminating your string and re-opening it. You have to "escape" the double-quotes with the backtick character.

Change this line:

```
write-host ("filename.txt written to "$_username"'s profile")
```

to this:

```
write-host ("filename.txt written to `"$_username`"'s profile")
```

Comment: Thanks - I upvoted your question. That should help :)

Answer (score 1):

Just take the quotes out from around the $_username variable and remove the parenthesis like so:

```
write-host "filename.txt written to $_username's profile"
```